# SQL insert based on select with multiple results

Tags: sql, select, insert

I'm trying to insert into a table based on values from a separate table.

Here's the script I'm drafting and getting error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

```
insert into tableproducts (proditemid,
prodprintlabel,
prodid) 
values (
(select i.itemid from tableitems i where i.itemorigin = 'NJ'),
'F',
(select max(p2.prodid)+1 from tableproducts p2)
)
```

The results I'm hoping for is any Items from NJ have Products created with a unique ID.

```
Ex: 
ItemID | ItemName | ItemOrigin
001       Item1       NY
002       Item2       NJ
003       Item3       NJ

Take ItemID 002 & 003 and insert into Products
ProdItemID | ProdPrintLabel | ProdID
005            T               010   (existing)
002            F               011   (new Item2)
003            F               012   (new Item3)
```

Thank you, in advance, for any guidance given.

-Chetta

Comment: the first sub-select is returning more than 1 record, the second is returning only 1

Comment: @Hugo Jones that's right

Comment: which rdbms are you using - Oracle, SqlServer?

Comment: @Shawn Iachetta, did you test my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to accomplish here. But, your first sub-query is not limited to one result. You can add a MAX() to it like you did with the second sub-query.

Comment: I'm sorry for the vagueness. I've updated with an example. Hopefully it better explains what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

I suspect are trying to write something like this:

```
insert into tableproducts(proditemid, prodprintlabel, prodid) 
    select i.itemid , 'F', coalesce(m.maxprodid, 1)
    from tableitems i cross join
         (select max(prodid) as maxprodid from tableproducts) m
    where i.itemorigin = 'NJ';
```

If so, this is the wrong approach to creating a sequentially enumerated column.  It should be declared as `auto_increment`.  The above query is subject to race conditions.

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889922/how-to-get-the-number-of-total-results-when-there-is-limit-in-query)?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sqlserver and you dont want to use autoincrement you can write code like this

```
insert into tableproducts (proditemid,prodprintlabel,prodid)
select i.itemid
,'F'
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order by i.itemid )+(select coalesce( max(p2.prodid),0)+1 from tableproducts p2 )
 from tableitems i where i.itemorigin = 'NJ'
```