# How to get the number of total results when there is LIMIT in query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
select * from table where id <= 10 limit 5;  // table has +10 rows
```

The number of result in the above query ^ is 10 rows. Now I want to know, how can I get the number of total result in this query:

```
select * from table where col = 'anything' limit 5;
```

How to calculate the number of all results *(regardless of `limit`)* in this ^ ?

Actually I want this number:

```
select count(*) as total_number from table where col = 'anything'
```

Now I want to know how can I get the number of total results without another query.

Comment: Because I like to tell user the number of all matched results and also the number of how many numbers he is seeing, something like this: *Showing rows 0-5 (34 total)*

Comment: @Strawberry What? The user just uses my website. Actually my website is something like google *(a search engine)*

Comment: @Strawberry This function counts just the number of results. So, if there is `limit` in the query, the output of that PHP function will be equal or less than limit number. In this case: `mysqli_num_rows <= 5` ! While I need to the number of total results regardless `limit`.

Comment: @Strawberry What you linked is not the same with my question. That question is explained how `found_roews()` works. But I want to select both limited data and the number of total matched results as unlimited.

Comment: FOUND_ROWS returns the 'unlimited' result set. mysqli_num_rows returns the number of rows in the result set. It's sure to be faster than the answer provided below. What else do you need?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a column, `total`, for example:

```
select t.*
     , (select count(*) from tbl where col = t.col) as total
from tbl t
where t.col = 'anything'
limit 5
```

As stated by *@Tim Biegeleisen*: *`limit` keyword is applied after everything else, so the `count(*)` still returns the right answer.*

Comment: I tested this query, But it has a syntax error *(according to what phpmyadmin says)*. Can you please take a look at it and if there is an error, fix it?

Comment: I replaced my real table name with 'table' and my real column name with 'col' in this error: *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as total from table t where match(t.col) against('anything') limit 5' at line 1 *

Comment: Note that rows in an RDBMS table represent unordered sets, so LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept.

Comment: Now there is not any error and it works. But not correctly. The output is always one rows. *(however there is a `total` column which shows the number of total result as well)*.

Comment: @Strawberry this current query doesn't need to `order by`. because always the result is just one row.

Comment: @Shafizadeh So what's `LIMIT 5`

Comment: @Strawberry I don't know... You can test it. I tested it. I wonder, Because always the result is just one row!

Answer (score 8):

You need the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in your query and FOUND_ROWS() function to do this:

```
DECLARE @rows int
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from table where col = 'anything' limit 5;

SET @rows = FOUND_ROWS(); --for a later use
```

Comment: This is the correct way of finding count of pre limit records.

Comment: @RavinderReddy So then which is the correct answer in this case?

Comment: As *output solutions* all seem correct. But why would one `count` all per each row??? None I believe. Hence, this should be correct answer.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how should I exactly use this! There is two query. So, when I have to execute them? Can you add some more code in your answer?

Comment: @Shafizadeh You have to execute them together in order to get all the rows returned.

Comment: I did it, but in this case there is just one column named `FOUND_ROWS()` and one row containing the number of total results. While I want to see both the number of total results **and data** (in this case all columns with 5 rows of matched data).

Comment: There is an error: *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @rows int
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from table where match(col)' at line 1*

Comment: `SELECT @rows := FOUND_ROWS();`

Answer (score 0):

Use sub-query

```
select *, (select count(*) from table where col = 'anything') as total 
from table where col = 'anything' limit 5;
```

Comment: This becomes hard to do if your query consists of numerous joins, and sub queries already.